# Is that possible the native code (C++ library) access Android file system in the application?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to past a string from java code to its library written by C++, which is compiled to libc++_shared.so using NDK. What I'm currently doing is creating a private text file and saving the string to it in the application launching. When function in native code is called, it will read the same file to retrieve the string.

The file is created successfully and accessible from the java code. I've hardcoded the location of the created file in the c++ code so that when the method in c++ is called, it can locate the file and read the contain of the file. But it seems not work.

Below is the location parameter that I've hardcoded in the c++ code before compiling. The location is returned by the java code after the file created.

```
#define WORD_FILE "/data/user/0/<App name>/files/otp.txt"
```

After that, a function call otp() will read the text file and return the string from it.

There is no way to debug beyond JNI, so I don't know if it is the location of the file incorrect or the Android doesn't allow library to access its file system.

If the solution of sharing a text file is not possible, is there any other way to pass a string from java code part to c++ library part in Android application?

Could anyone to me a hint?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hardcoded paths are a bad idea. See: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage. Also if you are just passing a String from Java to C/C++, that should be covered in any JNI tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build a bridge between your native and your Java/Kotlin code, then it's no problem to pass a String with your file path to your C++ code. In your native class, you'll need something like this:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_com_your_package_path_JniBridge_passString(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                                                 jstring file_name) {

   // do something with your jstring in c++, e.g convert it from jstring (java string) to a char*
    const char *name = env->GetStringUTFChars(file_name, nullptr);

    // I prefer to return booleans from native code to know if something  succeeded or not.
    return true;
}
```

In your app, you'd have something like this (in Kotlin):

```
// see how this class and function name are mirrored in your native method?
object JniBridge {
    
    fun doSomethingInNativeWithMyFileName(fileName: String): Boolean {
        return passString(fileName)
    }
    
    private external fun passString(fileName: String): Boolean
}
```

**Be aware though**:
This doesn't just work out of the box, it's just an example. If your project is properly set up, Android studio can help you and will suggest completion or fixes when building your bridge methods.
If you don't know what all this is or how to set it up, I suggest first reading up on the basics about NDK development [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk)

Comment: Thanks. Following your suggestion, I've solved to problem by modifying the C code, then using SWIG to generate JNI code automatically.

Comment: Glad to hear that!